# $C^1$ is not dense in Hölder space

Tags: banach-spaces, holder-spaces

> Let $\overline{\Omega}$ be a bounded, closed and convex set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$, the space of continuously differentiable functions on $\overline{\Omega}$, is not dense in the Hölder space $C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$, with $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

The problem has a hint, it says that if $f \in C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$, then extend it outside the compact set like $f(s(x))$ ($x \notin \overline{\Omega}$), where $s(x)=\{y: |x-y|=\operatorname{dist}(x,\overline{\Omega})\}$ (basically $f(x)$, for $x \notin \overline{\Omega}$, takes the value of the $f$ evaluated at the closest point $y \in \overline{\Omega}$ of $x$), and this is possible to define as $\overline{\Omega}$ is closed, convex. I do not see how to use the hint. Could you give me some insight on how to use this hint?

Comment: Your definition of $s$ doesn't make sense to me. Could you clarify this a little?

Comment: Another way to see this would be to note that $C^{0,\alpha}$ is never separable.

Comment: Now it is fixed. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a use for the hint either, but for the sake of having an answer here, I'll write a proof. Pick $x_0\in \overline{\Omega}$ and let $f(x)=|x-x_0|^\alpha$. This is a function in $C^{0,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$. Let $g$ be any function in $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$. Smoothness implies that $g$ is Lipschitz on $\overline{\Omega}$, which is the only property we need. Since $g(x)-g(x_0) = O(|x-x_0|)$,  it follows that 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{|(f-g)(x) - (f-g)(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|^\alpha}
= \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|^\alpha} = 1
$$
hence $\|f-g\|_{C^{\alpha}}\ge 1$.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain why the equality between the limits holds?