# Which functions are dense in this Hölder-space?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

> We are on the line $[0,T]$, let $a \in (0,1)$. Let $C^a$ consist of
>   those real functions such that:
>
> $|f|_a=\sup_{0\le s<t\le T }\{\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{(t-s)^a}\}<\infty$.
>
> Denote the norm $\|f\|_a=|f|_a+|f|_\infty$. Where $|\cdot|_\infty$ is
>   the standard supremum norm for continuous funtions.
>
> Using the mean-value theorem, we can show that the space
>   $\mathcal{C}^1$, the space of continuously differentiable functions,
>   is in $C^a$.

A theorem in a book I am reading states:

> Let $f \in C^a$ with $a \in (0,1)$, and let $b\in(0,1)$ be such that
>   $a+b>1$. The linear operator $T_f: \mathcal{C}^1\subset C^b\rightarrow
> C^b$ defined as $Tf(g)=\int_0^\cdot f(u)g'(u)du$ is continuous with
>   respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_b$. By density, it extends (in a unique
>   way) to an operator $T_f:C^b\rightarrow C^b.$

The author proves everything except from the density argument. From what I understand he refers to the classical result that if you have a dense subspace of a banach space, and you have a continous linear operator, you can extend it uniquely to the entire space? The problem I have is how is it dense. Because according to these links:

[$C^1$ is not dense in Hölder space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161651/c1-is-not-dense-in-holder-space)

[Polynomials not dense in holder spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360537/polynomials-not-dense-in-holder-spaces?rq=1)

$\mathcal{C}^1$ is not dense in the Hölder space. I think in the links they only use the norm $|\cdot|_a$, not $\|\cdot\|_a$, but if it is not dense w.r.t to the first norm, it can't be with respect to the other norm that is a sum of the first norm and the supremum norm?

Do you see what I am missing? What kind of density argument is used here?

Comment: I guess it's just a mistake. $\mathcal{C}^1$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}^0$, so if you're not paying attention, it's easy to believe it would also be dense in $C^b$, because $C^b \subset \mathcal{C}^0$. Of course we have a unique continuous extension to the closure of $\mathcal{C}^1$, and by Hahn-Banach continuous extensions to $C^b$. But since $\mathcal{C}^1$ isn't dense in $C^b$, these continuous extensions aren't unique. It could be, however, that there's a unique extension with the same norm.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you but I quite did not understand that. How do you use the Hahn-Banach theorem to show this? I see that it talks about functionals, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem , but here the value of the linear operator is a function not a real or complex number? And, would it be difficult to show the uniqueness you talk about, that there is a unique norm?

Comment: Brainfart on my part. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think you are correct so no need to say sorry, I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension and it talks about an extension the same way you do, and there Y may not be the real or complex numbers. So there is probably a way to do it.

Comment: We get the extension to the closure. That part is unproblematic. The question is whether we can extend to the whole space. If the codomain is finite-dimensional, Hahn-Banach gives the extension, but for infinite-dimensional codomain, an extension to the whole space might not exist. // $\mathcal{C}^1$ is complete in the $C^1$-norm, whether it's complete as a subspace of $C^b$ is a different question.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the book, in case we're missing some context? There are no useful norm-dense subsets of functions in $C^b$. The closure of $C^1$ in the $C^b$ norm is the little-oh space Hölder space $c^b$, which is a proper subspace of $C^b$ (of uncountable codimension).

Comment: @zaq http://www.springer.com/us/book/9788847028227, page 25.

Answer (score 5):

The appeal to "density" is a little sloppy. I believe the following is what the author meant:

1. The closure of $\mathcal C^1$ with respect to $C^\beta$ norm is the little Hölder space $c^{\beta}$ (defined by the condition $|f(x)-f(y)| = o(|x-y|^\beta)$ as $x-y\to 0$)
2. $C^{\beta+\epsilon}\subset c^\beta$ for every $\epsilon>0$.
3. Given $f\in C^\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta>1$, pick $\gamma <\alpha$ such that $\gamma+\beta >1$. Then $f\in c^\gamma$, hence the density argument applies and shows that the integral $\int fg'$ is bounded by $C\|f\|_\gamma\|g\|_\beta$. The latter is controlled by $C\|f\|_\alpha\|g\|_\beta$, as desired.

I don't have a suitable reference for (1), but this fact is not hard to prove directly: (a) smooth functions are in $c^\beta$; (b) $c^\beta$ is a closed subspace of $C^\beta$; (c) mollifying a $c^\beta$ function produces an approximating sequence that converges in $C^\beta$ norm; the key is that sufficiently small scales don't really contribute to the norm.

For reference, here is the relevant part of the source (page 25 in *Selected Aspects of Fractional Brownian Motion* by Ivan Nourdin).

[image: thm31]

The reference Young [67] is to the classical article [*An inequality of the Hölder type, connected with Stieltjes integration*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02401743), Acta Math. (1936) 67, 251-282. Young actually works with larger spaces of functions of finite $p$-variation, and I couldn't locate a relevant density argument there.  A more accessible source is a pair of blog posts by Fabrice Baudoin:

- [Lecture 6. Continuous paths with bounded p-variation](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/lecture-6-continuous-paths-with-bounded-p-variation/)
- [Lecture 7. Young’s integral](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/12/25/lecture-7-youngs-integral/)

Comment: Thank you very much for doing so much work and going and reading all the sources! I do not know so much about these spaces you mention, so I will try to learn more about it.